# How to deal with backslash apostrophes in a string?

Tags: python, string

This has been talked about in other posts but I have a string that goes:

```
u' yeah its gucci, wassup baby yellow everything this time you know 
what im talking about yellow rims, yellow big booty, yellow bones 
yellow lambs, yellow mp\'s,'
```

I want to turn mp\'s --> mp's. I understand that the computer reads \' as '             and when it's printed it's not show, but when I vectorize this sentence, the word becomes mp and s which I don't want.

The other option is to get rid of the apostrophe altogether but then i'll turn to ill and gets confused for the word ill. Is there anyway that I can deal with this? Encode it to something else?

Comment: what do you mean by "vectorize this sentence"?

Comment: I don't think the backslash is actually in the string. What you show in your question is how it might appear as a string literal in a Python program, but once evaluated it the backslash would disappear. Also, by-the-way, I think you would need to use `u''' yeah.....'''` to keep the newlines in the string otherwise the string definition would be a syntax error.

Comment: if what you want to type a string with a `'` inside without doing `\'`, all you need to do is use `"` for the string constructor like this `"python's magic"`

Answer (score 0):

Just do this "yeah its gucci, wassup baby yellow everything this time you know what im talking about yellow rims, yellow big booty, yellow bones 
yellow lambs, yellow mp\'s,".